# CosmosDB API selection: does it dictate how the data is stored, or only how we communicate with the instance?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When creating a CosmosDB instance, we can choose the API that we will use to communicate with the instance (e.g. SQL, MongoDB, Cassandra, etc.)

What is not clear to me is - does this selection dictates how the data is stored, or only the way we communicate with the instance? For example, if we choose MongoDB, does it mean that CosmosDB will store data in a MongoDB fashion?

Answer (score 1):

The choice of API does not change how the data is stored.  Cosmos DB always stores data using something called atom-record-sequence (ARS) which is essentially a set of primitive types, structs and arrays.  The database engine translates the native ARS format into the data structures used by the various APIs (i.e. json documents, table rows, etc.)

So the answer to your question is that the choice of API only impacts how you communicate with the databases for that Cosmos DB account.

As David Makogon points out in his comment on another answer, while the *way* the data is stored is the same regardless of the API used, the content of the data will be different because each API requires it's own metadata so that the underlying data can be projected into the format expected by each API.

Here is a good technical overview of how Cosmos works under the hood.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/a-technical-overview-of-azure-cosmos-db/

Comment: I had gone through the Microsoft Video over cosmos db on indexing, here is the link : youtube.com/watch?v=bscs9GAnSqM Its been mentioned in the video that JSON document is converted into a tree and then indexed through inverted indexed. Does is valid to all data models. or atom-record-sequence (ARS) are converted to JSON than to tree and then indexed.

Comment: @Sharad The data for all models is stored the same way.  I believe the sequence is, the incoming data is projected into a JSON document, then converted into a tree of properties, then it's stored in the ARS format.  I'll update the answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Data is always stored in the same fashion (as a bunch of json documents), only the way you interact with the data changes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction#develop-applications-on-cosmos-db-using-popular-open-source-software-oss-apis

Comment: True, data is all stored in Documents underneath. However, the actual data is stored differently depending on the protocol chosen. For example, there is different metadata in MongoDB API documents vs SQL API documents. And for graph, there is data specific to relationships between vertices. This is visible when, for instance, you query non-sql-api data via the sql api.