# Does data always stored in JSON format even if we choose MongoDB API, Cassandra, Tables, or Gremlin(Grapgh API)?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, multi-model-database

I was going through the Indexing policies article by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview
states that "Every time an item is stored in a container, its content is projected as a JSON document, then converted into a tree representation. I could able to relate it when we opt SQL API, Azure table storage API. I am still wondering what is the ultimate underlying structure inside CosmosDB? It is vary as per the data model we opt?

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471185/cosmosdb-api-selection-does-it-dictate-how-the-data-is-stored-or-only-how-we-c/59537645#59537645).

Comment: @Paul: I had gone through the Microsoft Video over cosmos db on indexing, here is the link : youtube.com/watch?v=bscs9GAnSqM Its been mentioned in the video that JSON document is converted into a tree and then indexed through inverted indexed. Does is valid to all data models. or atom-record-sequence (ARS) are converted to JSON than to tree and then indexed.